# Oracle SecureFile

Tags: oracle, blob, data-migration

In my current workplace, an existing app is being replaced by a new 3rd party app. The database of the existing app, in Oracle 10g, needs to migrated. The existing app stored various documents as BLOBs. Per the new app's data model, they store the documents in files. I am tasked with conversion of existing BLOBs to files.

There are around 5 million records amounting to a total of 1 TB.

I am wondering if we can leverage the idea of Oracle SecureFile in this process. We do have some Oracle 11g environments available. This is my idea:

1) Import the existing 10g BLOBs into 11g SecureFiles.
2) Convert the Oracle SecureFiles (DBFS) to Windows file system (CIFS?).

The advantage with this idea is that the BLOB to File conversion process would be native and is taken care of by Oracle (in other words, performant, tested and exception-handled process). I have no clue about the file system conversion though.

Experts, is this a feasible idea? Dont know if this helps... but the new app is on Oracle 11gR2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the blobs to docs and drop them in a dbfs. If you define the dbfs to use securefiles - recommended - and during the initial load with filesystem like logging, you have a good performant filesystem, comparable with nfs performance.
Problem with the windows environment is that you can not mount a dbfs native on windows (AFAIK). You could however mount it on Linux and pass in through to cifs. Not exactly an ideal solution but maybe useable as a workaround until native dbfs mount becomes available on Windows.

The filesystem like logging is good for performance, not for recovery or feeding to standby databases. This is because only the file metadata is logged, not the contents. You should include this knowledge in your recovery process, or swith to full logging after the initial load/conversion completes. That would be my preference.

dbfs is great, combined with advanced compression it can save quite a lot of space.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ik_zelf. "You can convert the blobs to docs and drop them in a dbfs" Can you elaborate on this please? As I mentioned, I was assuming that Oracle will do this conversion for me, if I migrate the 10g BLOBs to 11g where the BLOB would be implemented as SecureFile.

Comment: You will need to use the dbms_dbfs routines to add the blobs as files in dbfs. You can also write them to a regular fs and copy them to dbfs while mounted on Linux of using the dbfs client. During the upgrade, the blobs will remain blobs, AFAIK they are not converted to secureFiles during the upgrade of the database. To get the most advantage you will need to copy them to a table defined with secureFiles.

Comment: Thats the idea. I want to copy them to a table whose blob column is defined as SecureFile. It could be as simple as "Insert into 11gSecureFileTable (Select * from 10gBlobTable)".

Comment: Probably I m day-dreaming but the idea is that "Insert into 11gSecureFileTable (Select * from 10gBlobTable)" will convert all the existing 10g BLOBs into files in the fastest, least error-prone way possible. Once the files are there (as SecureFiles), the next step would be to copy/move them all into the new app's Windows file system.

Comment: you could copy them as listed, no problem. To convert them to files, you will need to add some metadata, here is where the dbfs package comes around the corner. See http://ronr.blogspot.com/2010/06/dbfs-is-great.html, maybe it explains something.